# PromQL query to select metrics whose values are included in a given multiple selection variable

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

In Grafana I need to create a *PromQL* query to select some metrics whose values are included in a given *multiple selection* variable.

For example:

- I have a custom variable `selectedStatus` which values are `1`, `2` and `3` with an "Include All option" (not sure what to specify as a custom value for this)
- And a metric `status`

and I want to select only those `status` which are selected in the `selectedStatus` (variable) dropdown.

For metrics

```
status{} 1
status{} 2
status{} 3
```

If I select to show `status` with value 1 (variable `selectedStatus` = `1`)

I could write something like this (which works if I want to select each `status` independently):

```
status == $selectedStatus # this filters out status whose value is not equal to the selected one
```

Now, If I would like to select `status`es which values are any of `1`, `2` or `3` (`selectedStatus` = `All`), how could I write the PromQL? (something like an equivalent to an `OR` in SQL)

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to filter by the value of a time series (in your case `status`) and not by the value of a label?

Comment: @trallnag yes: I want to filter by the value of a time series (`status`) and not by the value of a label.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in PromQL I can think of that would support this out of the box. But you could put whole PromQL expressions into Grafana variables you can then choose from in your dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following query:

```
status == 1 or status == 2 or status == 3
```

It should return `status` time series with values equal only to (1, 2 or 3).

The query uses `or` operator - see more details about this operator at https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators

Comment: This is really good. I need to find out how to make it work with the variable I have with an `All` option (as posted in the question).

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for negative example of **not equals to any of X** when I get into this page

found a solution:

```
(((status != 1) != 2) != 3)
```